# Give alert on second time page loads using Jquery

Tags: jquery, refresh, reload

I want to give a small alert that page is reloaded after refreshing the entire page.

This is what I have done to refresh the page:

```
 window.onunload = function () {
      alert("Page is refreshed");
}
```

And Onbody load I can give alert as

```
window.onload = function () {
    alert("Page is Loaded"); //<--This I dont want as only 
                             //when the page is loaded it gives me an alert.
 }
```

But I want to know that page is reloaded completely after refresh is done.

If page is refreshed by pressing F5 or clicking refrsh button or clicking on browsers back button I am giving alert as shown above but I would like to know how to give an alert after page is completely refreshed.(ie after refreshing the page is again reloaded after completely reloaded I need to give another alert)

Comment: @Zerkms-I have updated my question

Answer (score 1):

try something like this...

```
window.onunload = function () {
    localStorage['refreshing'] = true;
}

window.onload = function () {
    if(localStorage['refreshing'] === true) {
        alert('win');
        localStorage['refreshing'] = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: i forgot, it'll need a ttl of 20 seconds at least

Comment: +1 for being practical. Although i agree with @gdoron this feature does not sit well with the nature of web apps.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know how to give an alert after page is completely refreshed.

Web applications are **stateless** so it **can not be done**. you can never know if this is the first visit or second visit (unless you store your's visitors visits with some sort of Data Base.)

Answer (score 0):

DotNetter it is still unclear that what u really want But I guess document.ready method helps you out in some way

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   alert(page ready)
});
```

Hopeit helps